# Defining variables as start and end times WITHOUT dates-Python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I'm attempting to define two variables (StartTime, and EndTime) as fixed times WITHOUT dates. They will be used to start and stop a loop. I have had a difficult time formatting these variables due to issues with datetime versus strings etc. Here is a rough idea of my code and what I have tried:

Version 1.0: strptime

```
import time
import datetime as dt

currenttime=dt.datetime.now()
StartTime=dt.datetime.strptime('8:00:00 AM','%I:%M:%S %p')
EndTime=dt.datetime.strptime('5:00:00 PM','%I:%M:%S %p')

timemargin = dt.timedelta(seconds=60) 

if(StartTime-timemargin)<currenttime<(StartTime+timemargin) AND(EndTime- 
 timemargin)<currenttime<(EndTime+timemargin): 
   'do something'
```

V1.0 Outputs:

```
 StartTime
  datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 8, 0)

 EndTime
  datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 17, 0)
```

Now this is not ideal because I only want to compare the time NOT the date. How can I declare a variable ONLY as time and not as a date and time? This also applies for currenttime.

I know strftime is an option, but I am not sure if it will apply here. I have also seen other methods involving something along the lines of:

StartTime.minute to call the minute, but I'm not sure how to use this for my application.

Any recommendations?

Comment: What is the issue? Since you're only looking at timestamps, they can only be reasonably considered to be within a 24 hour period, so the date portion is irrelevant since you will always get `1900-01-01` as the date. The number of hours between those two datetime values is the same, regardless of whether you also get the date.

Comment: The issue is, sorry if I didn't make it clear, I don't care about the date in StartTime and EndTime. I only want them to be times.

Comment: But for the purposes of calculations, the format isn't an issue. Only when you want to represent them as strings which you a) already had in the first place or b) can use `strftime` to obtain after any calculations

Comment: You are correct. They aren't a problem. But for the sake of this code it make the most sense to be to simplify the time comparison. I could be making it too simple but it's just the way I thought about it.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to use `datetime.time` objects instead of `datetime.datetime`. If you already have `datetime` objects, just call their `time()` method to extract the time, ignoring the date, as a `time` object…

Comment: But if you convert to `time` objects you will get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'` when trying to use the `timedelta`

Comment: … but I don't think you want to do that, because a lot of things that make sense for a datetime (where you can specify "these are times the same day, even if I don't care what day it is" vs. "these times span a midnight, even if I don't care which midnight it is") don't make sense for a time.

Comment: @roganjosh You're too fast. :P Anyway, subtracting a `timedelta` is a perfect example of something that makes sense for a datetime but not for a time. What does it mean to subtract 3 hours from 2am? 11pm the previous night, of course… but you can't represent that as a time.

Comment: @abarnert I should have known you had follow-up comments to cover that :) For all the ways we're telling the OP it's better to keep it as a `datetime`, I do find myself being a little frustrated by this, even though it's totally logical.

Comment: I should clarify the reason for the timedelta calculation. I need it because this is controlling a small thermal camera that must take measurements at given intervals between 8AM and 5PM. I could survive without the timedelta comparison but wanted to include it just in case of some lag in time and it doesn't turn the loop on.

Comment: Your use of `timedelta` is not unjustified and I think you'll have a better time coming to terms with a `datetime` being intuitive for this (even if the date portion is nonsense) than trying to change the logic of your actual code.

Comment: Agreed. I will find a work around. Many thanks to all commentors.

Comment: Really, the problem is that a fully-general solution has to deal with the case where `startTime - timeMargin < 00:00`, even though that obviously isn't going to happen with a static time and margin of 08:00 and 00:01, so the fully-general solution is more complicated than you need—and may even be harder to understand even if it's easier to code up… I don't think it's a huge problem; either way you implement it should be fine. But I can see why it's frustrating.

Comment: I always struggle with dates and times in python, and it has always been frustrating. I really appreciate all the guidance you've all given me. ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO CLOSE...

All you need to do is change your .strptime() line to then call the .time() attribute

```
 StartTime=dt.datetime.strptime('8:00:00 AM','%I:%M:%S %p').time()
 EndTime=dt.datetime.strptime('5:00:00 PM','%I:%M:%S %p').time()
```

Comment: The issue with this is the OP will get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'`

Comment: While this solves the problem of only getting the time from the variables, it doesn't help with the calculation. However, I can use this if I make modifications to the if statement. I will mark it as the correct answer for this reason only.